# Retrieving website via API call from site and display to user

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I am developing an iphone app.

The first screen of my app shows a list of services available for the user.

The user than selects one of the services and goes to the next screen where they can order that service.

I need to retrieve the list of services using an api call from my website.

What is the the way to do so in IOS without affecting the user experience? I don't want the user to be waiting for me to retrieve the list of services from my site every time they access that page.

I am using the AFNetworking API to get the list of services now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking sounds good.

Make sure you use it asynchronous and with a completion block

e.g.

```
   NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = ...

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *request = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
    [request setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        ... handle your services
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        ... handle error
    }];


     [request start];
```

---

if the request is JSON, use the AFJSONRequest class